# Lightroom CC v5 - How to select flagged photos

Tags: lightroom

I had no problems with this when I used Lightroom Classic but in cc I cannot figure out this simple task. I cannot find it in the menu system.

When google I only find the classic way.

Can someone nice tell me how this is done in v5 Lightroom?

Comment: I finally found it. The funnel in the search box.

Comment: So make it as answer and after a day feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select flagged or star marked pictures use the funnel in the search box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution here. Could you perhaps add a screenshot? In my experience that makes an answer more useful to others who find it.

Comment: Thank your, added picture!